# Is a countable product locally convex?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ be a countable set. Consider the space $\mathbb{R}^X$ of real-valued functions on $X$ equipped with the product topology.

> Is $\mathbb{R}^X$ locally convex?

If not, is the space of real-valued bounded functions on X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product topology is always locally convex if the topologies in each fibre are locally convex. The space  $\prod_{x\in X} Y_x$, where each $Y_x$ is a locally convex space, is locally convex. This is due to the fact that basic neighbourhoods are given by products $\prod_{x\in X} V_x$, where finitely many satisfy $V_x\ne Y_x$, and $V_x$ is open. If each fibre is locally convex, given a point we may choose convex neighbourhoods $V_x'\subset V_x$ for the nontrivial components, and then $\prod_{x\in X}V_x'$ is a convex neighbourhood.

Answer (score 1):

It’s clearly locally convex. The basic open neighbourhoods on this product (can be any size) are convex, taking intervals at the non-trivial coordinates.